# Reducing an algebraic summation expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider the following elements of an algebraic series
$$\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)$$
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^Nc(\theta_i)$$
$$\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{\array{j=1 \\j\neq k}}^N\sum_{\array{i=1\\i\neq j\\i\neq k}}^Nc(\theta_i)$$
$$\frac{1}{N-2}\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{l=1}^N\sum_{\array{k=1\\l\neq k}}^N\sum_{\array{j=1 \\j\neq k\\j\neq l}}^N\sum_{\array{i=1\\i\neq j\\i\neq k \\i \neq l}}^Nc(\theta_i)$$

where all the other elements run until $(N-1)$

How can I write a general expression for this series, and can the summation and average of all the elements in the series can be written?

Comment: The argument of the sum only depends on $i$. Are you sure it is meant this way, shouldn't it also depend on $j, k, l$?

Comment: @Florian, yes each expression is actuly an average of all the possible configurations of $c(\theta_i)$ when we count $N,N-1,N-2...$  elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to look at two instances in order to see what's going on.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq j}}^Nc(\theta_i)}
> &=\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq i}}^N1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(N-1)\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)}
> \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq k}}^N\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq j,i\neq k}}^Nc(\theta_i)}
> &=\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq i}}^N\sum_{{i=1}\atop{i\neq j,i\neq k}}^N1\\
> &=(N-2)\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\neq i}}^N1\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(N-1)(N-2)\sum_{i=1}^Nc(\theta_i)}
> \end{align*}
>
> We deduce for positive integers $m<N$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{(N-m)!}{N!}\sum_{k_0=1}^N
> \sum_{{k_1=1}\atop{k_1\neq k_j, 0\leq j< 1}}^N\cdots
> \sum_{{k_m=1}\atop{k_m\neq k_j, 0\leq j<m}}^Nc(\theta_{k_m})
> =\frac{N-m}{N}\sum_{k_m=1}^Nc(\theta_{k_m})\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   which can be shown rigorously for instance by using induction by $m\geq 1$.

The general part corresponds to the examples above by
\begin{align*}
&(j,i)\to(k_0,k_1)\quad &(m=1)\\
&(k,j,i)\to (k_0,k_1,k_2)\quad &(m=2)
\end{align*}

We obtain for $m=3$ from (1):
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{(N-3)!}{N!}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{k_0=1}^N
\sum_{{k_1=1}\atop{k_1\neq k_j, 0\leq j< 1}}^N
\sum_{{k_2=1}\atop{k_2\neq k_j, 0\leq j<2}}^N
\sum_{{k_3=1}\atop{k_3\neq k_j, 0\leq j<3}}^N
c(\theta_{k_3})}\\
&=\frac{1}{N(N-1)(N-2)}\sum_{k_3=1}^Nc(\theta_{k_3})
\sum_{{k_2=1}\atop{k_2\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j< 1}}^N
\sum_{{k_1=1}\atop{k_1\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j<2}}^N
\sum_{{k_0=1}\atop{k_0\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j<3}}^N1\\
&=\frac{N-3}{N(N-1)(N-2)}\sum_{k_3=1}^Nc(\theta_{k_3})
\sum_{{k_2=1}\atop{k_2\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j< 1}}^N
\sum_{{k_1=1}\atop{k_1\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j<2}}^N1\\
&=\frac{N-3}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k_3=1}^Nc(\theta_{k_3})
\sum_{{k_2=1}\atop{k_2\neq k_{3-j}, 0\leq j< 1}}^N1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{N-3}{N}\sum_{k_3=1}^Nc(\theta_{k_3})}
\end{align*}

Comment: in the final result, the counting is not over the $i$'s. what does the counting of $k_0$ represent?

Comment: @jarhead: Typos corrected. Thanks for pointing at it.

Comment: should there be also a summation over $m$? how do you count here all the different $m$'s? I think a couple of baby steps for the last line are needed.

Comment: @markusScheurer, also the deduction is a bit vague...

Comment: After working on it for a while, I don't understand how to move to the last line (the deduction part), and how to switch the indexes to $k_m$ in the last line. The solution looks valid, but the steps must be clear, in order to see that there are no mistakes and that the majority of people would understand the solution outline.

Comment: @jarhead: I've added some info which might help  to    clarify   open  aspects.

Comment: At the last line I believe it is $(N-m)!/N$ rather then $(N-m)!/N!$.

Comment: @jarhead: When considering the special cases $m=1$ and $m=2$, we have $(N-1)!/N!=1/N$ and $(N-2)!/N!=1/(N\cdot (N-1))$ in accordance with the factors at the left-hand side of your second and third example.

Comment: I still can't figure out the the last two transitions, the deduction, and the last line, can you please provide an example on how you perform the math for $m=2$ or $m=3$?

Comment: I'm also confused with the last term. is there any meaning that the sum is indexed by$k_m$ (does the $m$ has a meaning there if it is a single sum), can it be written as a sum over $i$?

Comment: @jarhead: Example  added which should clarify the open points. $m$ is just a fixed number indicating the number of sums  we sum over.